# La instalación de Mysqldb falló con el código de error 1

Tags: python, windows10

Intenté instalar [esta aplicación](https://github.com/antoinecomp/moodbot) en Windows pero fallé, así que intento iniciar el programa instalando una por una las bibliotecas solicitadas. Sin embargo, tengo problemas para instalar `flask_mysqldb`. ¿Tendría una idea?

```
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\moodbot> python -m pip install flask_mysqldb
Collecting flask_mysqldb
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/e3/955c845efe1aacf30c8e2607470544ede36aa1044f6382c809f13e01410
4/Flask-MySQLdb-0.2.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.10 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (f
rom flask_mysqldb) (1.0.2)
Collecting mysqlclient (from flask_mysqldb)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/fd/83329b9d3e14f7344d1cb31f128e6dbba70c5975c9e57896815dbb1988a
d/mysqlclient-1.3.13.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-pack
ages (from Flask>=0.10->flask_mysqldb) (0.24)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (fr
om Flask>=0.10->flask_mysqldb) (6.7)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (
from Flask>=0.10->flask_mysqldb) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.14 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
 (from Flask>=0.10->flask_mysqldb) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packag
es (from Jinja2>=2.10->Flask>=0.10->flask_mysqldb) (1.0)
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient, flask-mysqldb
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptoo
ls, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\antoi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-sh9pwso_\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(to
kenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" ins
tall --record C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7ofoixao\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-manag
ed --compile:
    C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution o
ption: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /n
ologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,3,13,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.13 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\My
SQL Connector C 6.1\include" -IC:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users\antoi\AppData\Lo
cal\Programs\Python\Python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.1
4.26428\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\inclu
de" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\inclu
de\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Win
dows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /Tc_my
sql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    _mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.14.26428\\bin
\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C
:\\Users\\antoi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-sh9pwso_\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__
file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\a
ntoi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7ofoixao\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed wit
h error code 1 in C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sh9pwso_\mysqlclient\
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Has instalado MySQL? Al parecer faltan las cabeceras.

Comment: @César, No lo hice, pero ahora sí. Lo instalé y configuré. Cambié el error en consecuencia, simplemente no verifiqué si puedo conectarme a una base de datos porque el tutorial sobre como instalar MySQL que seguí [dijo en la parte sobre conectarse a base de datos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwQyZz6cNGU)  que Navicat ya no existe